# How to find only file names that contain a specific string?

Tags: bash, grep, find

I have a list of for then 1000 files. and I have a list of strings (additional.txt) that I would like to look up in all those files in current directory. That list (more than 1000 entries) looks like this:

```
head additional.txt
aadrah2
aahmed93
aaich2
aalfon2
...
```

If I find any of these strings in any of these files I would like to record that file name and put it in an another file, say named: addonsE.txt

So far I tried these two commands:

```
for f in `cat additional.txt`; do grep -rnw '/var/spool/torque/server_priv/accounting/' -e ${f}  ; done > addonsE.txt 

for f in `cat additional.txt`; do grep -inr ${f} /var/spool/torque/server_priv/accounting/ ; done > addonsE.txt
```

and both of them are giving me this output, which is not what I want.

```
/var/spool/torque/server_priv/accounting/additional.txt:1:aadrah2
/var/spool/torque/server_priv/accounting/additional.txt:2:aahmed93
/var/spool/torque/server_priv/accounting/additional.txt:3:aaich2
```

Comment: *"which is not what I want."* .. Please edit your Q to show what you **do** want. I can't tell if you mean the `grep` isn't working as you expect, or if the information included in `/var/spool/torque/server_priv/accounting/additional.txt:1:aadrah2` what you want. Good luck.

Comment: so my file names look like this: 20140608  20141208  20150613  20151217  20160618  20161220  20170621  20171223  20180624  20181224  20190625  20191225  20200625  20201225  20210626  20211226  20220627  20221227. If say string "aadrah2" is found in file: 20170621 , I want that file name to be recorded in addonsE.txt

Comment: I'm not sure what "I have a list of for then 1000 files" means, so I'm going to kind of ignore it. To find any file in the current directory that contains any of the strings in `additional.txt`, you just specify that file to grep with `-f`. Since they're apparently fixed strings (not regex patterns) you add `-F`. Finally, you can tell it what to do with subdirectories. Assuming you want to ignore subdirectories, that would be: `grep -F -l --directories=skip -f additional.txt > addonsE.txt`. (and the question is a better fit for SuperUser, since it ends up only being about how to use grep).

Comment: As far as getting the file names without the full path, it's probably easiest to do something like `pushd /var/spool/torque/server_priv/accounting/; grep [as above]; popd`, only specifying a full path to `addonsE.txt` to get your output in the right place.

Comment: Replying in comments with information that should be in the body of the question is a S.O. anti-pattern. Readers should be able to understand your problem just from reading your question. Good comments from Jerry above, they should solve your problem for you. Good luck.

Comment: Did you just want to put `| sed 's/:.*//' | xargs -L 1  basename` after the `done`?

Answer (score 0):

the output that you already have is a good starting point. You can split it by delimiter colon, take the first token and make it uniq:

```
for f in `cat additional.txt`; do grep -inr ${f} /var/spool/torque/server_priv/accounting/ ; done | awk -F: '{print $1}' | uniq > addonsE.txt
```

Comment: You should copy/paste that into http://shellcheck.net.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind a single `regex` monstrosity, and nothing needed special `regex` escaping  :

```
echo $'aahmed9\n   aaich02 \naalfon21' |
```

---

```
gawk -v __="$( 
   mawk NF=NF RS='^$' FS='\n+' OFS='|' <( echo 'aadrah2
                                                aahmed93
                                                aaich2
                                                aalfon2' ) 

  )" -p- -be 'BEGIN { gsub("^[|]|[|]$", "", __)
                                       FS = __ 
  } 1 < NF { print (_ = FILENAME) != "-" \
                                  ? _ : "/dev/stdin"
             nextfile 
  }'
```

---

```
/dev/stdin
```

---

```
    # gawk profile, created Sun May 28 14:35:46 2023

    # BEGIN rule(s)

    BEGIN {
     1      gsub("^[|]|[|]$", "", __)
     1      FS = __
    }

    # Rule(s)

     3  1 < NF { # 1
     1      print (_ = FILENAME) != "-" ? _ : "/dev/stdin"
     1      nextfile
    }
```

> `FS == "aadrah2|aahmed93|aaich2|aalfon2"`

The moment it found the 1st match, it instantly outputs the current `FILENAME`, and proceed to the next file instead of reading the rest of the current one.